# Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': undefined ionic3

Tags: ionic3, phonegap-plugin-push

Getting the following error

Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for ios
Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': undefined
(node:723) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): /bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by reinstalling the cocoapods.

sudo gem install cocoapods

It worked in my case.